# How to say OK to all the popups in excel by using vba

Tags: vba, excel, popup

I am trying to open some files in a specific web page by the following hyperlink which is saved in a specific cell. While executing the below-mentioned line (hyperlink.follow) I am getting warning ⚠ popup which I need to say ok.
I want to make this automate, please somebody help me
Worksheets(1).cells(2,1).hyperlinks.follow

I tried **application.displayalerts = false/true** before and after the line, but it doesn't work

Comment: Most of the time, you can pass in a `vbYes`or `True` into functions that might start a confirmation popup, in order to avoid user interaction.

Comment: application.displayalerts works on the application, microsoft Excel in this case, therefore it indeed will have no effect on the IE popups

Comment: One ugly solution could be "SendKeys": `SendKeys "{ENTER}"`. But make sure the dialog is visible when sending the key, for example wait a second before SendKeys (really ugly solution because you can never make sure one second is enough... but most of the time it works™)